# Swift get OneTimePassword (OTP) in class

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I’ve read about how to achieve this using Storyboards and UI text elements and it seems to be pretty straightforward, however, I am building a hybrid app so I need to intercept this OTP in the controller and feed it to another event listener which will pass it to my app, so in this scenario I cannot make use of ios text input fields etc but surely there is a way to hook into the devices capability to recieve and parse it’s value ?

Comment: No, there isn't. iOS offers the detected OTP as a keyboard shortcut for text fields of the appropriate type. Your code can only get the code once it is "typed" into the text field

Comment: Are we talking about the same thing though. I am taking about when you sign up for tinder and add your phone number and then you get an sms message with a code in it, sometimes an input on the screen gets auto filled with this number, I wasn’t to be able to receive that number in a class/controller and send it elsewhere to another service

Comment: Yes. That’s what I was referring to. The code isn’t exposed by any api. The user can select it from the shortcut bar to type it in automatically. I have never seen it autofilled.  If an app does that then it is using some other method, perhaps its own push notification.  It would be a privacy violation for iOS to automatically type a code from a text message into a text field

Answer (score 0):

You can't parse security code. It only works this way:

> If the system can parse a security code from an SMS message, the
>   QuickType bar shows the code for up to three minutes after it has been
>   received. If a security code arrives while the text input view is
>   selected, the system pushes the incoming code to the QuickType bar.

---

**Reference:** [Swift Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/about_the_password_autofill_workflow)

---

**UPD:** You can access code once it pasted in `UITextField`

Comment: But it’s possible to auto populate an input with that code so is there any way to get the code in a controller and send it to another service ?

Comment: @Kravitz You can listen for value change of `UITextField` and when it reaches number of characters you need, try to send it wherever you want. However, there is no way to access it directly. Auto population and other related stuff done by iOS itself.

Comment: This done by setting `contentType` to `UITextField`, then `iOS` will advice autocomplete to user.